# Parsing “He went there, and that, too, when it was dark”

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the example "He went there, and that, too, when it was dark"

How does one analyse the sentence after the main clause 'He went there'?

1. What function is “and that too,” performing?
2. What will be the main clause for subordinate clause “when it was dark"?

Answer (score -1):

> "He went there, and that, too, when it was dark"

is a shortened form of > "He went there, and *he did* that, too, when it was dark"

**That** is a demonstrative pronoun with the referent "**the action of going there"**"

**Too** = additionally

Thus we have: "He went there, and *additionally, he went there, even* when it was dark" (in which "**even**" is an implied emphatic.)

The main clause is *"He went there when it was dark"* and *"and that, too,"* is an parenthetic, emphatic phrase - I suspect it is a free modifier.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard. Does it mean that "and that, too" is not gramatically connected with the main and subordinate clause?